# Why is my BP neural network's accuracy too low?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The assignment is recognizing handwritten digits by BP neural network. I have tried add hidden layer, increase units and change activation, momentum, but the result shows:

> Test Acc: 0.11142061281337047

the splitting dataset X:(1797,64) Y(1797,)

```
np.random.shuffle(X)
np.random.shuffle(y)
offset1=int(len(X)*0.6)
offset2=int(len(X)*0.8)
offset3=len(X)-1
X_train, y_train = X[0:offset1,:], y[0:offset1]
X_valid, y_valid = X[offset1:offset2,:], y[offset1:offset2]
X_test, y_test = X[offset2:offset3,:], y[offset2:offset3]
```

And my neural network:

```
def create_network():
  # TODO
  net = tf.keras.Sequential()
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
  net.compile(
      optimizer='adam',
      #tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False), 
      loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", 
      metrics=["accuracy"])
  return net


def train_network(network,
                  X_train,
                  y_train,
                  X_valid,
                  y_valid,
                  n_epoch=32,
                  batch_size=64):
  n_iter = 0
  network.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=n_epoch, validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid))
  #opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False) #SGD=Stochastic Gradient Descent



net = create_network()
train_network(net, X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid)

# evaluate on test set:
y_test_pred = net(X_test)
y_test_pred = np.argmax(y_test_pred.numpy(), axis=1)
print("Test Acc:", accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_test_pred))
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are actually training the network, why aren't you using network.fit?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have renewed, please check, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NebiyouTen, I agree with what you said. But in fact `np.random.shuffle` doesn't return anything. Maybe you need to do some modifications:

```
shuffled_ids = np.arange(len(x))
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_ids)
shuf_x = x[shuffled_ids]
shuf_y = y[shuffled_ids]
```

And here is an alternative way to shuffle the data:

```
random_state = np.random.get_state()
np.random.shuffle(x)
np.random.set_state(random_state)
np.random.shuffle(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model and training are correct, one issue I see is, You are shuffling `x` & `y` separately. `np.random.shuffle` will modify both arrays in place. After you do that the training points will no longer be correctly matched with the correct labels. Hence, your training and prediction won't work as expected. You can do something like,

```
# shuffle the ids
shuffled_ids = np.arange(len(x)))
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_ids)
# index x & y with the same shuffled numbers, 
# so the correct relationship is maintained 
shuf_x = x[shuffled_ids]
shuf_y = y[shuffled_ids]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved, What a stupid point I ignore, LOL